# Spring data jpa maps only partial data mapped to entity

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below is my repository which extends spring data jpa's JpaRepository

```
 public interface GamesDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<Game,Integer>{ }
```

and the entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="game")
public class Game implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="code")
    private  String code;

    @Column(name="name")
    private  String name;

    @Column(name="description")
    private  String description;

    @Column(name="url")
    private  String providerURL;

    @Column(name="is_portrait")
    private  Boolean portrait;

    @Column(name="image_url")
    private  String imageURL;

    @Column(name="created_at",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private  Timestamp createdAt;

    @Column(name="modified_at",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private  Timestamp modifiedAt;

    @Column(name="is_active")
    private  Boolean active;

    @Column(name="is_active_inflight")
    private  Boolean activeInflight;

    @Column(name="is_blacklisted")
    private Boolean blacklisted;

    @Column(name="provider_id")
    private  Integer providerId;

    @Column(name="position")
    private Integer position;

    /*@OneToOne(mappedBy="id")
    @Column(name="provider_id")
    private Provider provider;*/

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="game_tag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="game_category", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Category> categories;


    /*public Provider getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }*/

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
```

But when i am doing

```
Game game=gamesDetailsRepository.findOne(id);
```

the resulting data is not mapped to my entity,while i am able to get data like name, image_url etc but not data like description and provider_id

here is my mysql table for the same

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| code               | varchar(45)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| name               | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| description        | text         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| url                | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| is_portrait        | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| image_url          | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_at         | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| modified_at        | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL              | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| is_active          | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| is_active_inflight | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| provider_id        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| position           | int(11)      | YES  |     | 1                 |                             |
| is_blacklisted     | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Why only some column data's are mapped to my entity and other's are not.
I have checked in mysql tables,the data is present in the coloumn.Any suggestions??

Comment: I think you have missed the getter and setter of column in your entity class .

Comment: I there any other possible reason?

Comment: I have made getters and setters correctly,for one field that was the issue

Comment: rest of them still have the same problem

Comment: @guptaprobable it's present there